# How to stop a pod job in openshift platform?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I am a newbie to the Kubernetes world and don't have much context on openshift/Kubernetes.

Here is the requirement: when I run the below command which lists the all running jobs:

$ oc get pods

Name            READY    STATUS    RESTARTS  AVG

abc-job1-dev    1/1      Running     0       38h

abc-job2-dev    0/1      Completed   0       7d

Here one job1 is running 24/7 then how can pause/stop it for some time when job 2 starts running and then resume it once the job2 task is completed?

Answer (score 2):

In the Openshift Console you can stop the POD using Deployments Menu.

In the left side Menu bar, Expand Workloads menu.
Workloads -> Deployments

In the right pane for deployments, select relevant project and then under the "Details" tab You see the Colored circle, you can take down the pod using the down arrow symbol next to that circle.
Similarly use teh Up arrow symbol to start the pod if you have stopped that.

Comment: Thanks for the description - I'm currently working my way into OpenShift and was looking in the wrong place in the GUI ^^